# Constrain total width of Bootstrap page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm customizing a Bootstrap template trying to teach myself Bootstrap. Is it possible to set the max-width of the page? When I try to set the max-width in css under the body tag it only affects the width of the main section for some reason, not the whole page. I am trying to constrain the whole page to be only 75% of the available screen space.

Here is a link to the files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UGeCe2TcsXVCEO_ReNsOoCNFXInnfU54

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A demo would help you to get an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

you could try a container class as explained here:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/
```

here is an example:
    https://codepen.io/kentarofujiy/pen/MMGqzw

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to learn by editing the template I linked to but it doesn't seem to be responding. I've tried adding it in different places and nothing seems to change.

Comment: mate, nobody would download the files you posted on gdrive. Why dont you copy and paste your code on the codepen I posted so people can help?

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what the relevant code would be. Appreciate the help tho.

Comment: Please don't format URLs as code. Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. Please see [answer].